# Cache a dynamically created image in Django

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a view that allows for a user to upload a file with data that is used to generate a graph to be displayed to the user. The graph is a separate view that is linked to via an image tag within the file upload view.

I'm looking to cache that dynamically created image (e.g. graph) so if the user navigates away from the view that serves the graph image so when they return it will still be visible and not requisite to re-upload the file and generate the graph.

I've read the django cache documentation, but can't seem to get it working. At the moment I only need page-view caching and not full site so my attempts are as follows neither of which worked:

## Caching within the views

```
@login_required
@cache_page(60 * 60) # cache for 1 hour
def upload_file(request):
   ...

@login_required
@cache_page(60 * 60) # cache for 1 hour
def graph(request):
   ...
```

## Caching via the URLs

```
url(r'^file_upload/$', cache_page(60*60)(views.upload_file), name='file_upload'),
url(r'^graph/$', cache_page(60*60)(views.graph), name='graph'),
```

Any suggestions on what I could try differently or modifications to my current attempts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you save the upload and the image? That way someone could request them by id and you could just serve the image?

Comment: The graph image isn't a model. The graph image is purely a .png generated by the view which is then referenced by the file upload view. I can't use .save() on a non-model can I?

Comment: the image have a common shareable unque name ?

Comment: @aus_lacy will you want to ever access the graph after the cache expires? without requiring the data to be reuploaded?  will users ever want to view all the graphs that they have generated? Will you want require authentication to view certain graphs?

Comment: @dm03514 the users won't need to review previous graphs because it's purely a utility web app that is for fast real-time visualization of graph data on a case by case basis.